# Finding the probability of the two events of multiplication of two whole numbers

Tags: probability

> Two whole numbers are randomly selected and multiplied. Consider two events $E_1$ and $E_2$ defined as:
>   $E_1:$ Their product is divisible by $5$
>   $E_2:$ Units place in their product is $5$.
>
> Which of the following statements is/are correct?
>
> $A)$ $E_1$ is twice as likely as $E_2$
>   $B)$ $E_1$ and $E_2$ are disjoint
>   $C)$ $P(E_2|E_1) = \frac{1}{4}$
>   $D)$ $P(E_1|E_2) = 1$

Note: This question has more than $1$ correct answers

---

**My Attempt:**

I just got $D)$ as one of the answers which is quite an obvious thing.

Also, $B)$ can not be the answer as the two sets are clearly intersecting.

The problem lies in the rest of the options. How do I even start here? The whole numbers are infinite as we know it. The only thing that can be said is that the product should contain its units digit as $5$ or $0$. But then what? How do I define the cases here?

Answer (score 1):

The numbers are "whole numbers" and I suspect you mean "integers" by that.

Then "randomly selected" is actually *meaningless*, because a canonical uniform distribution on integers does not exist.

If nevertheless the selection takes place on base of some distribution then correctness of answers A) and C) *depend* on that distribution, and since nothing is known about the distribution it cannot be stated that these answers are correct.

Comment: Just for the info, the answer given in my book is $\text{C})$ , $\text{D})$